# TableRowSorter returning incorrect SortOrder

Tags: java, sorting, tablerowsorter

I have made a `TableRowSorter` which should update the cycle in which each column is sorted from `ASCENDING => DESCENDING => ASCENDING => DESCENDING => ...` to `ASCENDING => DESCENDING => UNSORTED => ASCENDING => DESCENDING => UNSORTED => ...`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class ADU_SortOrder<M extends TableModel> extends TableRowSorter<M> {

    public ADU_SortOrder(M model) {
        setModel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
        List<? extends SortKey> sortKeys = getSortKeys();
        if (sortKeys.size() > 0) {
            List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>(getSortKeys());
            keys.set(0, new SortKey(column, setNextOrder(sortKeys.get(0).getSortOrder())));
            setSortKeys(keys);
            return;
        }
        super.toggleSortOrder(column);
    }

    private SortOrder setNextOrder(SortOrder order) {
        switch (order) {
            case ASCENDING:
                return SortOrder.DESCENDING;
            case DESCENDING:
                return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
            case UNSORTED:
                return SortOrder.ASCENDING;
            default:
                return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
        }
    }
}
```

---

In the given example I will try to describe what I expect to happen and what actually happens. You have a `JTable` with two columns. The `SortKeys` which are used at the start make it so that the last sort in each column were so that the columns were `SortOrder.ASCENDING`

What I expect would happen here would be the following.

```
Sort Order in: Column 1           Column 2
Start:        ASCENDING           ASCENDING
Click C1:     DESCENDING          ASCENDING
Click C1:      UNSORTED           ASCENDING
Click C2:      UNSORTED          DESCENDING
Click C1:     ASCENDING          DESCENDING
Click C2:     ASCENDING           UNSORTED
```

What actually happens:

```
Sort Order in: Column 1           Column 2
Start:        ASCENDING           ASCENDING
Click C1:     DESCENDING          ASCENDING
Click C1:      UNSORTED           ASCENDING
Click C2:      UNSORTED           ASCENDING
Click C1:     DESCENDING          ASCENDING
Click C2:     DESCENDING          UNSORTED
```

As you can see instead of getting the sort order of the column clicked, the `TableRowSorter` gets the last sort order applied and then just applies the next sort order to the next column clicked. How would I be able to treat each column individually and update the columns so that it worked as expected?

---

Here is a MCV. I apologise for not including one previously.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter.SortKey;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class MVC extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8809862571237032846L;

    private MVC() {
        setTitle("MVC");

        createAndRunGUI();

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void createAndRunGUI() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        String[] tableHeaders = {"Col 1", "Col 2"};
        String[][] tableData = {
                {"Hi", "Animals"},
                {"Bob", "Of"},
                {"Phil", "The"},
                {"Dog", "World"},
                {"Cat", "Include"},
                {"Pill", "Fish"},
                {"Dab", "Ants"},
                {"Bob", "Hippos"},
                {"Fill", "Humans"},
                {"Space", "TVs"},
                {"Up", "Is"},
                {"Now", "That"},
                {"Even", "Right"},
                {"More", "Person"},
                {"Data", "?"}
            };

        JTable table = new JTable(tableData, tableHeaders);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        ADU_SortOrder<TableModel> tableSorter = new ADU_SortOrder<TableModel>(table.getModel());
        List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>();
        //keys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey( 0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
        //keys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey( 1, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
        tableSorter.setSortKeys(keys);
        table.setRowSorter(tableSorter);

        JScrollPane myScrollTable = new JScrollPane(table);
        myScrollTable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

        JPanel cont = new JPanel();
        cont.add(myScrollTable);

        getContentPane().add(cont);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MVC();
    }

    private class ADU_SortOrder<M extends TableModel> extends TableRowSorter<M> {
        public ADU_SortOrder(M model) {
            setModel(model);
        }

        @Override
        public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
            List<? extends SortKey> sortKeys = getSortKeys();
            if (sortKeys.size() > 0) {
                List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>(getSortKeys());
                keys.set(0, new SortKey(column, setNextOrder(sortKeys.get(0).getSortOrder())));
                setSortKeys(keys);
                return;
            }
            super.toggleSortOrder(column);
        }

        private SortOrder setNextOrder(SortOrder order) {
            switch (order) {
                case ASCENDING:
                    return SortOrder.DESCENDING;
                case DESCENDING:
                    return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
                case UNSORTED:
                    return SortOrder.ASCENDING;
                default:
                    return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2**
Looking at the specific method `toggleSortOrder` whilst the program is running it becomes apparent that the problem is with the part of code which says `setNextOrder(keys.get(0).getSortOrder())`. This is because when the code returns `getSortKeys()` as an `ArrayList` the size of the list is only ever `0` or `1`. This means that when the length of the list is `1` the code `get(0)` returns the last column sorted but the code `get(column)` would cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. So how can I allow the program to get the `SortKeys` for every column?

```
@Override
public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
    System.out.println("Column: " + column);
    List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>(getSortKeys());
    System.out.println("List Size: " + keys.size());
    if (keys.size() > 0) {
        keys.set(0, new SortKey(column, setNextOrder(keys.get(0).getSortOrder())));
        setSortKeys(keys);
        return;
    }
    super.toggleSortOrder(column);
}
```

---

**Edit 3**

Using [Andreas'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) suggestion I created a way to be able to use `keys.set(column, new SortKey(column, setNextOrder(keys.get(column).getSortOrder())));`

```
List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>();

@Override
public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
    System.out.println("Column: " + column);
    System.out.println("List Size: " + keys.size());
    if (keys.size() > 0) {
        keys.set(column, new SortKey(column, setNextOrder(keys.get(column).getSortOrder())));
        setSortKeys(keys);
        return;
    }
    super.toggleSortOrder(column);
}

private SortOrder setNextOrder(SortOrder order) {
    switch (order) {
        case ASCENDING:
            return SortOrder.DESCENDING;
        case DESCENDING:
            return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
        case UNSORTED:
            return SortOrder.ASCENDING;
        default:
            return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
    }
}

private void initialSortOrder(M model) {
    for(int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        keys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey( i, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    }
}
```

However using this method column 1 can be sorted but only the words `Of` and `Hippo` can be sorted in the second column. I know this has turned into a very long question and sorry but I do appreciate any help

Comment: Please see [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149). Also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Andreas I included a MCV and really would appreciate any help

Comment: So what did you see when you ran the code with a debugger?

Comment: @Andreas It showed that the system works correctly. It just does not get the last `Sort Order` from the expected column. Instead it gets it from the last sort as described in the question

Comment: So... It doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @Andreas I shall clarify. It does not work as I expected it too and I do not understand how to make it work as expected but the code does seem to work.

Comment: Maybe `sortKeys.get(0)` should be `sortKeys.get(column)`?

Comment: @Andreas I attempted this. Unfortunately it produced  further unexpected results of only one column sorting and when clicking on the other column it wouldn't do anything

Comment: I bet, if you look at (or log) the value of `keys` right before `setSortKeys(keys)`, you'll see your problem.

Comment: @Andreas Okay. Thank you for the information. I will try this in the morning and let you know

Comment: @Andreas As you said the problem is with the keys. The `keys.size()` is only ever 1. Do you know how I could make it so that `getSortKeys()` returns a list with a `SortKey` for each column?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the sort keys. If you want to sort by column 3, with secondary sort by column 1, you add two keys to the list, one for col3 and one for col1, in that order. Having sort keys for every column, in column order, makes no sense.

Comment: @Andreas So how would I achieve what I am wanting to do if not via sortkeys?

Comment: You do it with sort keys, but when user clicks C2, don't you want to sort primarily by C2, with optional secondary sort? E.g. if I click C1, C3, C3, C2, shouldn't sort keys be `C2 asc, C3 desc, C1 asc`? At least, *I* would expect that the last column I clicked would be the primary sort.

Comment: @Andreas I am sorry for any confusion. In the actual scenario, the columns are not related to each other. So they should have individual sorting orders like I described in the `expected outcome` in the question.

Comment: But it is a *single* table. The columns are not sorted independently. The *rows* are sorted according the sort keys.

Comment: @Andreas Not on my table. I will be posting a code review in a few days of the code and will link it for you. But for now I would like to work out this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this, I needed to add a few more if statements and one or two variables.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class ADU_SortOrder<M extends TableModel> extends TableRowSorter<M> {
    public ADU_SortOrder(M model) {
        setModel(model);
    }

    boolean firstTime = true; //Needed in case there are any initial sort keys
    int columnHolder = -1;

    @Override
    public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
        List<? extends SortKey> sortKeys = getSortKeys();
        if(sortKeys.size() == 0) { //For if there are no initial sort keys
            List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>();
            keys.add(new SortKey(column, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
            setSortKeys(keys);
            return;
        }

        if (sortKeys.size() > 0 && columnHolder == column || firstTime) {
            if(firstTime) {
                firstTime = false;
                columnHolder = column;
                if(column != sortKeys.get(0).getColumn()) {
                    List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>(getSortKeys());
                    keys.set(0, new SortKey(column, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
                    setSortKeys(keys);
                    return;
                }
            }

            List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>(getSortKeys());
            keys.set(0, new SortKey(column, setNextOrder(sortKeys.get(0).getSortOrder())));
            setSortKeys(keys);
            return;
        } else if(sortKeys.size() > 0 && columnHolder != column && !firstTime) {
            List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>(getSortKeys());
            keys.set(0, new SortKey(column, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
            setSortKeys(keys);
            columnHolder = column;
            return;
        }
        super.toggleSortOrder(column);
    }

    private SortOrder setNextOrder(SortOrder order) {
        switch (order) {
            case ASCENDING:
                return SortOrder.DESCENDING;
            case DESCENDING:
                return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
            case UNSORTED:
                return SortOrder.ASCENDING;
            default:
                return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
        }
    }
}
```